# ¿Cómo puedo leer json anidados en C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, http

Esta es la `url` de la que quiero obtener datos para entender como desglosar un string `json` en sus correspondientes clases en C#.
`https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeId/440?format=json`
Este es un pequeño estracto, en el que se ve que es un objeto en el que una propiedad es una lista de Coches (Results):

```json
{
  "Count": 14,
  "Message": "Response returned successfully",
  "SearchCriteria": "Make:440",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Make_ID": 440,
      "Make_Name": "ASTON MARTIN",
      "Model_ID": 1684,
      "Model_Name": "V8 Vantage"
    },
    {
      "Make_ID": 440,
      "Make_Name": "ASTON MARTIN",
      "Model_ID": 1686,
      "Model_Name": "DBS"
    }
  ]
}
```

He probado con dos librerías, `System.Text.Json` de dotnet 5, y `Newtonsoft.Jso`n, pero con ninguna he conseguido obtener los Coches. Escribiendo la `url` en el navegador obtengo todos, así que los datos deben estar ahí.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeId/440?format=json";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// Microsoft System.Text.Json
Results resultado = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Results>(resp);
//foreach(var item in resultado.Coches) Console.WriteLine(item);

// Newtonsoft.Json
Results resultado2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(resp);
foreach(var item in resultado2.Coches)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

public class Coche
{
   public int Make_ID { get; set; }
   public string Make_Name { get; set; }
   public int Model_ID { get; set; }
   public string Model_Name { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
   public int Count { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public string SearchCriteria { get; set; }
   public List<Coche> Coches { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar  foreach para que imprimas todo lo que tengas en `Results`

```
var url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMakeId/440?format=json";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var resultado = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(resp);
```

te recomiendo esta pagina [para convertir tu json a clases c#](https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("Count")]
        public long Count { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("SearchCriteria")]
        public string SearchCriteria { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Results")]
        public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("Make_ID")]
        public long MakeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Make_Name")]
        public MakeName MakeName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Model_ID")]
        public long ModelId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Model_Name")]
        public string ModelName { get; set; }
    }
```

con el `foreach` recorres la lista de lo que tienes en tu `JSON Results`

```
foreach(var item in resultado.Results ) Console.WriteLine(item.MakeName );
```

aqui te dejo un [ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rchnxA)

Answer (score 0):

Con Newtonsoft haces un for super simple

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

foreach (var item in jsonObject["Results"])
{
    var id = item.Make_ID;
}
```

O mira esta otra respuesta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16646559/5774044

Comment: He errado al diseñar mis clases. Results debería ser Result, y contener un Results, y no una lista de Coches.

Comment: En caso de que no sea una lista solo seria accedes a los valores directamente o mapear o un objecto. Es casi el mismo ejemplo, solo que ya no tendras que usar ningun iterador.